# extracting a word from a string in unix

Tags: unix, sed, awk

i wanted to extract the word prior to a pattern from a string in unix.How can i acheive this?

eg:
say the string is 
"sv_z = sample.scr"
in the string i have to search for ".scr".If found in the string i have to extract that whole word. In this example the output should be
sample.scr. The delimiter to arrive at the word can be balnk space,double quotoes or equal to.

Here's a few more examples:

```
sv_z=sample.scr
sv_z=urhk_dbCall("sample.scr")
sv_z="sample.scr"
```

Here's my expected output:

```
sample.scr
sample.scr
sample.scr
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using `grep`:

```
grep -o '[^ "=]*\.scr' file
```

Explanation:

- The `-o` flag matches the pattern exactly.
- `[ ... ]` is a character class. If a carat (`^`)  is used as the first character in this class, it is a negation of the class, it effectively means, "none of the following characters".
- `*` says match whatever the last character was, zero or any number of times.

*EDIT:*

Alternatively, if you require more strictness you'll need Perl-regex and a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). In the example below, this will ensure that the match is followed by, a double quote, a space or an end of line. Also, you could change the star (`*`) into a plus sign (`+`) which means match once or more times. So this would filter out things like: `.scr`. But it's not clear from your example input *exactly* what you're looking for here. Good luck.

```
grep -oP '[^ "=]*\.scr(?=("| |$))' file
```

Comment: You need to escape that "." or it'll match "unscr" in "unscramble". You also may want to change the * to a + if the OP doesn't want to match ".scr" on it's own. I also think that there's probably some terminating RE required (maybe something like `([ "=]|$)` but then you'd need to exclude that somehow from the printed expression) so it matches ".scr" but not ".scrabble" but the OP hasn't really told us about that yet.

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks Ed, some valid comments there particularly the escape. Missed that somehow. Added a lookahead to be more strict.

Answer (score 0):

In this awk script I'm using a variable "d" to contain the list of allowed delimiters to save repeating them multiple times in the script:

```
$ cat file
sv_z=sample.scr
sv_z=urhk_dbCall("sample.scr")
sv_z="sample.scr"
sv_z="unscrambled"
sv_z="sample.scrambled"

$ awk -v d=' "=' 'match($0,"["d"][^"d"]+\.scr(["d"]|$)") { $0=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); gsub("["d"]",""); print NR, $0 }' file
1 sample.scr
2 sample.scr
3 sample.scr
```

Compare with the posted grep -o solution:

```
$ grep -n -o '[^ "=]*.scr' file
1:sample.scr
2:sample.scr
3:sample.scr
4:unscr
5:sample.scr
```

Notice those last 2 lines that you probably don't want in the grep output.

Comment: this command seems to work.But in certain cases this command still failing. For example
`exebatch mrbx4004 $B2K_SESSION_ID scrFilename.scr $ListFile4 $OutputReport $RipFile`
from the above string i need to extract the name scrFilename.scr, that doesnt seem to be working. Please help.

Comment: Works fine for me. Is it possible there's tabs before/after the string instead of blanks or your line ends in control-Ms or something? The code I posted WILL work for your posted requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Mistake was from my side.  
But one more thing,I need to extract all the stringswhic matches the pattern given, even if  the pattern is coming more than once in the same line.  
For example in the below code i need to extract both `ubixres.scr` and `CheckSact.scr`. Is this possible?  
`sv_q = urhk_TBAF_SetKeyScript("bafe3012.optionblk.key-f2|ubixres.scr||CheckSact.scr")`

Comment: Yes, you'd need to put the match() call in a loop and modify $0 each iteration to strip off the front part that matched.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
 awk -F= 'NR==1{print $2}{FS="\""}NR>1{print $2}' file
```